# How to Split SQL column and get a part at condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am use SQL Server 2008 in this solution.

I have a table tbltrans:

```
ID     money    datepay (nvarchar(20))
1       10         21/10/2016
```

SQL Update command:

```
UPDATE dbo.tbltrans
SET money=0 
WHERE RIGHT(datepay, 7) = '10' AND RIGHT(datepay, 4) = '2016'
```

this command not return any error and not update column money.

please help fix or any solution the same.

Thankyou!

Comment: Because your update statement didn't find that record.  Double check what doing a RIGHT(datepay,7) does.  I think you'll find that it doesn't just return two digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**  See John Cappelletti's answer above, converting that text to a DATE will make everything easier.

Yeah, you'd have to use a substring of sorts to parse that text.  You can check that it is not doing what you'd like in a basic SELECT:

```
SELECT TOP 100 RIGHT(datepay, 7), RIGHT(datepay, 4) FROM dbo.tbltrans
```

If it's a date field, date functions will do what you want:

```
UPDATE dbo.tbltrans
SET money=0 
WHERE MONTH(datepay) = 10 AND YEAR(datepay) = 2016
```

If it's not a DATE you may have to CAST/CONVERT first:

```
UPDATE dbo.tbltrans
SET money=0 
WHERE MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,datepay,103)) = 10 AND YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,datepay,103)) = 2016
```

Comment: thankyou your answer. It has solved the problem for my project by use `WHERE MONTH(CONVERT(DATE,datepay,103)) = 10 AND YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,datepay,103)) = 2016`

Answer (score 2):

Use convert to get datepay as a date

```
Update dbo.tbltrans 
   Set money=0 
 Where Convert(Date,datepay,103) = '2016-10-21'
```

Comment: Based on the original query I think the OP wants to only update any records where month = 10 and year = 2016

Comment: yes, i only want update var month and var year. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `datepay` is a `DATE` type you could rewrite it to this:

```
UPDATE dbo.tbltrans
SET money=0 
WHERE MONTH(datepay) = 10 AND YEAR(datepay) = 2016
```

The reason your query isn't getting any results is in your `WHERE` statement you are saying `RIGHT(datepay,7)` which returns the 7 characters from the right, in this case that would be `10/2016` not `10` so your query should be:

```
UPDATE dbo.tbltrans
SET money=0 
WHERE RIGHT(datepay, 7) = '10/2016'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case `datepay` is a string the expression `RIGHT(datepay,7)` will return '10/2016'. In order to obtain only '10' you should use `SUBSTRING(datepay,4,2)`

Comment: thankyou, this is error then i fix to `WHERE SUBSTRING(datepay,3,2) = '10' AND SUBSTRING(datepay, 7, 4) = '2016'` but return no error and no update.

Comment: sorry my fault, it should be SUBSTRING(datepay,4,2)